# Understanding numpy vectorization

Tags: python, numpy

I came across performing calculation for euclidian distance using numpy vectorization, [here](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/#array-programming-in-action-examples). Calculation done is:

[image]

```
>>> tri = np.array([[1, 1],
...                 [3, 1],
...                 [2, 3]])

>>> np.sum(tri**2, axis=1) ** 0.5  # Or: np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(tri), 1))
array([1.4142, 3.1623, 3.6056])
```

So, to understand, I tried:

```
>>> np.sum(tri**2, axis=1) 
array([ 2, 10, 13])
```

So basically, `tri**2` is squaring each element: `[[1,1],[9,1],[4,9]]`. Next, we sum each sub-array element to get `[1+1, 9+1, 4+9] = [2,10,13]`

Then we take square root of each of them.

But I didnt get where are we doing the subtraction `qi-pi` as in the formula? Also I felt we should be getting single value: [`√((1-1)^2+(9-1)^2+(4-9)^2)=9.43`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%88%9A((1-1)%5E2%2B(9-1)%5E2%2B(4-9)%5E2))

Am I missing some maths here or python / numpy understanding?

Comment: You are most certainly missing the math here, you haven't performed subtraction yourself or have neither used a function which does it for you.

Comment: You did not do that yet. That would be `np.sum((tri[:,0] - tri[:,1])**2, axis=1)**0.5`

Comment: @QuangHoang so what does `np.sum(tri**2, axis=1) ** 0.5` do? I thought the linked site is trying to find euclidean distance only. Did I read it wrong?

Comment: It does what you described it. That's the **norms** or **lengths** of row vectors, or as the link describe *the Euclidean distance of each point from the origin (0, 0)*

Comment: ohh so it just found L2 norm of each row ,that is, `[√(p0^2+q0^2),√(p1^2+q1^2),√(p2^2+q2^2)]`, not √{(q0^2-p0^2)+(q1^2-p1^2)+(q2^2-p2^2)} ?

Comment: @QuangHoang sorry for taking up attention this way, but your answer to my other question about numpy calculation was good. Did you delete it because you felt it did not answer the modified question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two vectors `p` and `q` represented as `np.array`:

```py
dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((q - p) ** 2))
```

There is also [`np.linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) which computes the same thing:

```py
assert np.isclose(dist, np.linalg.norm(q - p))
```